# NSLocaleGroupingSeparator returns empty space instead of apostrophe since iOS 11 (Swiss / German locale)

Tags: ios, objective-c, locale, ios11

In my Calculator app I use the system's call to the character to use for display grouping (a.k.a thousands separator).

```
[[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleGroupingSeparator];
```

For iOS 9,10 in German and Swiss regional locales I got an apostrophe (which seems correct to me). Since iOS 11 it returns an empty space. Other locales that use either dots or commas as thousands separators are still fine.

So on iOS 9/10 I get:
10'000'000

And on iOS 11 I get this:
10 000 000

Any idea? Did some official rule change ? Swiss / German customers are definitely not happy with the chance.

Comment: What is the language and region set to on the device in question? What localizations does your app support?

Comment: App is localised ~40 languages. I insist this changed from iOS9/10 to iOS 11. If you want an example to test you can use my region (french Swittzerland or fr_CH). You can see clearly on iOS 9 it was an apostrophe and on iOS 11 it became a space.

Comment: TIL Wikipedia says the apostrophe is discouraged now in Switzerland for non currency values.  Of course the most common usage of a calculator has to deal with currencies but I don't know what the users are using the calculator for :-) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Digit_grouping